# How to create a custom template for a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have the following below which I have used to create a custom post type and a custom taxonomy.

Within the products section I've created the categories "monitors" & "consumables".

I have then created the template taxonomy-monitors.php, is that correctly named for the monitors category? Also what is the url I need to visit to see only the monitors category using that template?

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'products',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),   
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' ),
        )
    );
}

function news_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'products',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Product Categories' ),
            'sort' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products-category' )
        )
    );      
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_init' );
```

UPDATE
[image]

Answer (score 15):

### Templates

See the [Template Hiearchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) for a more detailed break down of how WordPress chooses the template.

For a *taxonomy term* `slug` ('monitors' your example) in the taxonomy `taxonomy` (e.g. 'products') WordPress will *try* to use the following templates (in this order)

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{slug}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
taxonomy.php
archive.php
index.php
```

For your 'monitors' taxonomy term page, WordPress will use

```
taxonomy-products-monitors.php
```

**if** it exists. If it doesn't, then for that taxonomy it will fallback to

```
taxonomy-products.php
```

and so on.

### Permalinks

The following url should point to the 'monitors' products page:

```
 www.example.com?products=monitors
```

You have also specified an url rewrite, so assuming the rewrite rules have been flushed and there isn't a clash, the following should also work

```
 www.example.com/products-category/monitors
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. I now have a template `taxonomy-products-monitors.php`, went to the permalinks section and clicked save (that flushes it right?) then went to the page `http://www.neurosignsurgical.com/v2/products-category/monitors` but it still shows a 404. Really don't understand why!

Comment: That does flush it, yes. Keep in mind that terms with now posts will probably display a 'nothing found'. If the first link works find, then its a permalink issue. You should [use this plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to diagnose it. A template won't effect a 404.

Comment: I've tried adding new products and categorising them as monitors, the first link gave a 404 and so did the second one. Tried the plugin (I'll update the question with a screenshot).

Comment: Sounds like you haven't flushed your permalinks. Go to the Settings > Permalinks page and just hit 'Save' again to force an update of the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 7):

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888951/wordpress-custom-post-type-taxonomy-template

```
 <?php 
get_header();


do_action('genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap'); ?>

<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
<?php do_action('genesis_before_content'); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <main class="content"> 
            <?php
                $case_study_cat_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
                $case_study_cat_name = get_queried_object()->name;
            ?>
                <h2><?php echo $case_study_cat_name; ?></h2>
            <?php
                $al_tax_post_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'success_stories', // Your Post type Name that You Registered
                    'posts_per_page' => 999,
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'success_stories_category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $case_study_cat_slug
                        )
                    )
                );
                $al_tax_post_qry = new WP_Query($al_tax_post_args);

                if($al_tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
                   while($al_tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
                        $al_tax_post_qry->the_post();
                        echo '<div class="post-excerpt">'; 
            ?>
                        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="entry-title-link"><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <div class="entry-content"> <?php echo excerpt(35);  ?> </div>

                        </div>
            <?php
                    endwhile;
                    endif;

            ?>
        </main>         

    </div>  
</div>          

<?php

do_action('genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap');
get_footer();
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For this, add the following code in the functions.php (located in the theme folder):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_cw_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
//create a custom taxonomy name
function create_cw_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Topics', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Topic', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' => __( 'Search Topics' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Topics' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Topic' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Topic:' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Topic' ),
'update_item' => __( 'Update Topic' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Topic' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Topic Name' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Topics' ),
);
// taxonomy register
register_taxonomy('topics',array('post'), array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),
));
}
```

I have found it here and here i found how to create Non-hierarchical Taxonomy
https://www.wpblog.com/create-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress/